# which socket is best with realtime laravel application pusher or socket.io or some thing more better

Tags: laravel, websocket, socket.io, pusher, webapi

i have a use case where user orders a service from mobile app using laravel api. As the service is requested it appears on the admin dashboard. I want to ask which socket service i should use. I want to answers considering pricing , efficiency with Laravel framework and ease of use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pusher is the paid service and Socket.io is open sourced but you need Redis server if you want to use this. then you have to pay for the Redis instance. you can reduce the price by using the Redis server, but you need to integrate manually when in Pusher, everything is fully managed by them.